# android app has stopped

Tags: android, react-native

[image: screen]

Я пытаюсь запустить Android приложение в эмуляторе, в процессе сборки ошибок нет. На девайсе приложение также не запускается.

Мой AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sleepschool"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      tools:replace="icon, label"
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Нашла одну ошибку в stacktrace android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window

Comment: Анна, переведите на русский язык, на русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы на русском языке.

Comment: Приложите стектрейс ошибки. Так как иначе вам никто ответ не даст. Но осмелюсь предположить, что имя активити в манифесте неправильное. com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity, при том что ваш главный package name com.sleepschool

Comment: Анна, должны же быть какие-то логи ошибок, приложите их. В режиме debug запустите и посмотрите